# I can't get values from div inside the form tag in Django

Tags: python, django

I am passing a context dictionary from view to the HTML template its rendering the values on the web page fine. These values are render in the div which is inside the form, I also have a submit button. My main purpose is that when I click on the button it get the values that I pass before in div back to the views and print in the terminal but its showing None in the terminal. Following is my code.

view.py

```
django.contrib.auth.models import auth
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def main_view(request):

    if request.method=='POST':

        company_name=request.POST.get('company_name']
        employ_name=request.POST.get('employ_name')
        print(company_name)
        print(employ_name)
        return redirect('/')

    else:

        context={
        'company':"Rapidev",
        'name':"Usama" 
        }

    return render(request,'main.html',context)
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="my_form" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="main_div">
    <h1 id="company_name" >{{company}}</h1>
<p id="employ_name" >{{name}}</p>
</div>


<button type="submit">Get Values</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which value you want? You don't have any input field to input any data which are submitted when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: I want to get the values which are in h1 and p tag inside the div. How do I do that?

Comment: Those are the values you passed as context from views.py which can be printed there directly. Why are you using form?

Comment: I am passing values as context from views.py in the template I want to get those values back from the template in the view and print in the context. Is there any other way to this then kindly tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` doesn't have any `<input>` fields, so it passes no data to the `main_view` function.  You want something like:

```
<form id="my_form" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="main_div">
      <h1 id="company_name" >{{company}}</h1>
      <p id="employ_name" >{{name}}</p>
    </div>

    New company_name: <input type="text" name="company_name" /><br />
    New employ_name: <input type="text" name="employ_name" />

    <button type="submit">Get Values</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue and, tried this solution but no way i can pass value from `<p>` to `<input>`

```
<div>
<p id="sec">24</p>
    
<input type="hidden" name="sec" />
</div>
```